# How do I simplify a website redirecting program in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

So, my goal was to have it so that when the main button was clicked it would automatically redirect to a certain page in a new tab by doing something along the lines of

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function() {
    addselect("List of gems", "gemstones.org")
    addselect("Whatever", "A url"
}
```

So that it would be very simple to make the  tags be created, and then have the program redirect depending on what its InnerHTML was.

But so far I only have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 align="center">Misc Info</h1>
  <p>Select a website to go to.</p>
  <select id="searches">
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button tyoe="button" id="submit">Go to list</button>
  <script>
  function addWebsite(name, url) {

      var select = document.getElementById('searches');
      var text = document.createTextNode(name);
      var option = document.createElement("OPTION")
      option.appendChild(text);
      select.appendChild(option);

  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am stuck and clueless, any suggestions

Comment: 1. I have a hard tie guessing what you want from the code you posted. 2. You have typos and never call anything name or id="submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try to combine 2 onclick function () ??

```html
<button onclick="function1(); function2()">
```